# Parsing a NMEA String using strok in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, delimiter

I am trying to parse a GNRMC string using strtok function with delimiter **","** , Everything was going well when i noticed something different which i was not expecting.
If String contains continuous **",,"** then strtok overshooting and print function misplacing the real data , My aim is to print Number **0** when there's no data available in between to consecutive **",,"**

How do i do it.?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
 char str[] = "$GPRMC,105954.000,A,3150.6731,N,11711.9399,E,0.00,96.10,250313,,,A*53";
 char* Message_ID = strtok(str,",");
 char* Time = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Data_Valid = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Raw_Latitude = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* N_S = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Raw_Longitude = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* E_W = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Speed = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* COG = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Date = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Magnetic_Variation = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* M_E_W = strtok(NULL,",");
 char* Positioning_Mode = strtok(NULL,",");

 double Latitude = atof(Raw_Latitude);
 double Longitude = atof(Raw_Longitude);

  printf("The Message ID is : %s\n", Message_ID);
  printf("The Time is : %s\n", Time);
  printf("The data valid is : %s\n", Data_Valid);
  printf("The Latitude is : %f\n", Latitude);
  printf("The N_S is : %s\n", N_S);
  printf("The Longitude is : %f\n", Longitude);
  printf("The E_W is : %s\n", E_W);
  printf("The Speed is : %s\n", Speed);
  printf("The COG is : %s\n", COG);
  printf("The Date is : %s\n", Date);
  printf("The Magnetic_Variation is : %s\n", Magnetic_Variation);
  printf("The M_E_W is : %s\n", M_E_W);
  printf("The Positioning_Mode is : %s\n", Positioning_Mode);

    return 0;
}
```

Output Window
[image: Output Window]

Comment: strtok does not support empty fields. You need to check before calling and advance in your program by the number of repeated delimiters.

Comment: strsep() looks what i wanted, But string.h doesn't have that function, I am using CodeBlocks with GNU GCC Compiler, A Console project.

Comment: Do not post text output as an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are after detecting only *one specific character* (like `','`)  the straight forward approach would be using good old `strchr()`.

```
 char str[] = 
   "$GPRMC,105954.000,A,3150.6731,N,11711.9399,E,0.00,96.10,250313,,,A*53";

 char* message_id = str;

 char* time = strchr(message_id, ','); *time = '\0'; ++time;
 char* data_valid = strchr(time,","); *data_valid = '\0'; ++data_valid;
 char* raw_latitude = strchr(data_valid,","); *raw_latitude = '\0'; ++raw_latitude;
 ...
```

A tricky macro could simplify the use:

```
#define FIND_AND_NUL(s, p, c) ( \
   (p) = strchr(s, c), \
   *(p) = '\0', \
   ++(p), \
   (p))
```

Use it like this:

```
 char str[] = 
   "$GPRMC,105954.000,A,3150.6731,N,11711.9399,E,0.00,96.10,250313,,,A*53";

 char* message_id = str;

 char* time = FIND_AND_NUL(message_id, time, ',');
 char* data_valid = FIND_AND_NUL(time, data_valid, ',');
 char* raw_latitude = FIND_AND_NUL(data_valid, raw_latitude, ',');
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I use my own strtok function that is very simple but has two differences with original: (1)
delimiter is only a single character instead of a string (2) if the string to parse has two consecutive delimiters, the function returns an empty non-NULL token "". This is very convenient for parsing NMEA messages.

```
char *strtok_fr (char *s, char delim, char **save_ptr)
{
    char *tail;
    char c;

    if (s == NULL) {
        s = *save_ptr;
    }
    tail = s;
    if ((c = *tail) == '\0') {
        s = NULL;
    }
    else {
        do {
            if (c == delim) {
                *tail++ = '\0';
                break;
           }
        }while ((c = *++tail) != '\0');
    }
    *save_ptr = tail;
    return s;
}
```

The non-recursive version:

```
char *strtok_f (char *s, char delim)
{
    static char *save_ptr;

    return strtok_fr (s, delim, &save_ptr);
}
```

So, your example (note ',' instead of "," delimiter and strtok_f instead of strtok function):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "$GPRMC,105954.000,A,3150.6731,N,11711.9399,E,0.00,96.10,250313,,,A*53";
    char* Message_ID = strtok_f(str,',');
    char* Time = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Data_Valid = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Raw_Latitude = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* N_S = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Raw_Longitude = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* E_W = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Speed = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* COG = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Date = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Magnetic_Variation = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* M_E_W = strtok_f(NULL,',');
    char* Positioning_Mode = strtok_f(NULL,',');

    double Latitude = atof(Raw_Latitude);
    double Longitude = atof(Raw_Longitude);

    printf("The Message ID is : %s\n", Message_ID);
    printf("The Time is : %s\n", Time);
    printf("The data valid is : %s\n", Data_Valid);
    printf("The Latitude is : %f\n", Latitude);
    printf("The N_S is : %s\n", N_S);
    printf("The Longitude is : %f\n", Longitude);
    printf("The E_W is : %s\n", E_W);
    printf("The Speed is : %s\n", Speed);
    printf("The COG is : %s\n", COG);
    printf("The Date is : %s\n", Date);
    printf("The Magnetic_Variation is : %s\n", Magnetic_Variation);
    printf("The M_E_W is : %s\n", M_E_W);
    printf("The Positioning_Mode is : %s\n", Positioning_Mode);

    return 0;
}
```

Result now:

> The Message ID is : $GPRMC
>   The Time is : 105954.000
>   The data valid is : A
>   The Latitude is : 3150.673100
>   The N_S is : N
>   The Longitude is : 11711.939900
>   The E_W is : E
>   The Speed is : 0.00
>   The COG is : 96.10
>   The Date is : 250313
>   The Magnetic_Variation is :
>   The M_E_W is :
>   The Positioning_Mode is : A*53
>   C:\Users\froca\Desktop\strtok>

Note that "Magnetic Variation" and "M_E_W" are now empty tokens. That's the key.